# I have built a nodejs app with morgan module as a logger

Tags: node.js, logging, routes, morgan

I'm facing an issue to add custom message to each logs. My requirement is to add custom message for individual logs according to their route. How to do that ?

lets say ,

```
requested the URL http://localhost/user/login

user fails the login with invalid password
```

I want my log to have a custom message as wrong password. This message will change for each and every route.

Comment: What does it mean "I want my log to have a custom message as wrong password"? instead of "user fails the login with invalid password" you want "user fails the login with wrong password"?

Comment: What have you tried? [ask]